# Ubuntu 20.04 can't change default application for mp3

Tags: gnome, settings

Setting a default application open .mp3 files doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04. When I click on the set default option via the UI nothing happens. This doesn't seem to happen for any other file extensions. Does anybody else have this issue?[image: Set Default open with mp3]

Comment: Did you solve this? For me none of the answers work.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus have a look at using XDG https://youtu.be/z3F0hTigMvU

Comment: `xdg-*` stuff works as expected, but I don't want to open my media files in a terminal, I want to be able to double-click them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, it seems like a bug. I, however, need other users to confirm this is occurring to them. A workaround has been to use [xdg-utils](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-utils/)

So to set mp3 to open with a specific application: `xdg-mime default vlc.desktop audio/x-mp3`

See here for more details: https://superuser.com/questions/21626/ubuntu-change-the-default-program-used-to-open-a-type-of-file

Comment: This only works in the terminal. When execute `xdg-open myfile.mp4` it opens my files with the correct application, but when I double-click the same files in Nemo, it still opens in the wrong application.

Answer (score 5):

Open a terminal, navigate to your file, and type:

```
mimeopen -d yourfile.mp3
```

The output should look like this:

```
Please choose a default application for files of type application/xxx

1) vlc
2) mpg123

Choose application #
```

Choose your application number.  Your output may be different than mine.  You can then run it either from the terminal, like this:

```
mpg123 *.mp3
```

Or double click on the file, it should now open with the application you set as default.

Cheers!

Comment: Really cool tool. Didn't know about it. Thanks. I'm still getting the same problem. It doesn't switch to "the application you set as default".

So my default is VLC and I'm trying to switch it to Rhythmbox. When I double click on the file it still runs as VLC.

Comment: finally, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem as described in 20.04, can't change defaults for music (flac, mp3). "Default applications" settings doesn't recognize VLC as an alternative for music, and it doesn't work with the two alternatives that show: I changed to Rhythmbox, but it still uses Videos to play music. Right clicking on individual files doesn't give the alternative to set default programmes.

Edit: now worked it out through Nautilus: file properties - open with - default.